# Привязка атрибута src к тегу img VUE JS

Tags: vue.js

Хочу при клике на кнопку обратиться к полю image и вывести его как картинку, а не текст. 
Если обращусь в другому полю, например, к полю film, данные отобразятся. Значит проблема именно в привязке атрибута...Помогите пожалуйста. Очень срочно..

Не судите строго, новичок

```js
new Vue({
    el: '.movieApp',
    data: {
      
        randomMovie: null,
        movies: [
            {
                film: "Мстители, 2012",
                seen: true,
                id: 1,
                image: 'https://st.kp.yandex.net/images/film_iphone/iphone360_263531.jpg'
            },
            {
                film: "Зеленая книга, 2018",
                seen: false,
                id: 2,
                image: 'https://st.kp.yandex.net/images/film_iphone/iphone360_1108577.jpg?width=360?width=180'
            },
            {
                film: "Аватар, 2009",
                seen: false,
                id: 3,
                image: 'http://www.icanbecreative.com/res/freeweb/2011/04/avatar-photoshop-tutorial.jpg'
            }
        ]
    },

    methods: {
        random: function () {
            console.log(this.randomMovie)
            var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.movies.length);
            this.randomMovie = this.movies[rand].image
            console.log(this.randomMovie)
           
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <link href="movieApp.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
                <button v-on:click="random()">Рандом</button>
                <div class="container">
            <p>Посмотри сегодня:</p>
            <span>{{ randomMovie }}</span>
            <img 
                v-bind:src="this.movies.image" 
                alt='Постер'
            >
        </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

при привязке src ты привязываешься к `movies.image`, а надо к `randomMovie`

Comment: спасибо огромное!!!

Comment: забыл еще уточнить, не используй `this` в шаблонах, в шаблоне у тебя уже контекст твоего компонента задан, плюс в компоненте лучше хранить именно индекс рандомного фильма, а уже в шаблоне использовать конструкцию `movies[randomMovieIndex].image`

Comment: Спасибо за рекомендации! Учту обязательно)